# When I added a timer function it wouldn't draw my "dots"

Tags: javascript, p5.js

So I am making a simple aim training game in HTML5 using javascript with the library p5.js . The code works when the timer is commented out and the timer works inside other code but when I put the time into this code it doesn't work.

```
let x;
let y;
let circle;
let dots = [];
let score = 0;
let gameover = false;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(1080, 800);
    xycircle();
}

function draw() {
    if (gameover) {
        gameend();
    } else {
        background(100, 100, 255);
        scorer();
        for (let dot of dots) {
            ellipse(dot.x, dot.y, dot.circle, dot.circle)
        }
    }
};

function xycircle() {
    for (i = 0; i < 25; i += 1) {
        dots.push({
            x: random(1080),
            y: random(100, 800),
            circle: random(25, 50)
        })
    };

};

function mousePressed() {

    var hit = false;
    for (let dot of dots) {
        if (dist(dot.x, dot.y, mouseX, mouseY) < dot.circle / 2) {
            dots = dots.filter(dot1 => dot1 !== dot)
            hit = true;
            if (dots.length === 0) {
                xycircle();
            }
        }
    };

    if (hit)
        score++
    else
        gameover = true;
};

function scorer() {
    fill(20, 75, 200);
    rect(0, 0, 1080, 75);
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    text(score, 950, 50)
    text(timeremaning, 900, 50)
    fill(255, 255, 255);
};

//function timer() {
//   let time = Date.now();
//   let timeremaning = 60000
//   if (timeremaning > time) {
//       timeremaning--
//   }
//   if (timeremaning === 0)
//       gameend()
//};

function gameend() {
    background(255, 0, 0);
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    text("GAME OVER", 540, 400);
    text("Your score was " + score, 540, 420);
};
```

All I want is a 1 or 2 minutes timer that doesn't break my code. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `timer` function isn't quite right.  I'm not sure why you are comparing the value of `timeremaning` (which is misspelled BTW) to `now`, that approach doesn't make sense to me.  Seems like you just want to decrement the time remaining, and when you get to zero, trigger `gameend()`, and set `gameover` to `true`.  Without setting `gameover`, the end state does not trigger correctly.

Note: you will probably need to adjust the timer's starting value, as this takes longer than a minute to run.

Without knowing exactly what you're shooting for, the below changes seem to end after a prescribed time.

Hope this helps.

```js
let x;
let y;
let circle;
let dots = [];
let score = 0;
let gameover = false;
let timeremaning

function setup() {
    createCanvas(1080, 800);
    xycircle();
}

function draw() {
    if (gameover) {
        gameend();
    } else {
        background(100, 100, 255);
        scorer();
        for (let dot of dots) {
            ellipse(dot.x, dot.y, dot.circle, dot.circle)
        }
    }
};

function xycircle() {
    for (i = 0; i < 25; i += 1) {
        dots.push({
            x: random(1080),
            y: random(100, 800),
            circle: random(25, 50)
        })
    };

};

function mousePressed() {

    var hit = false;
    for (let dot of dots) {
        if (dist(dot.x, dot.y, mouseX, mouseY) < dot.circle / 2) {
            dots = dots.filter(dot1 => dot1 !== dot)
            hit = true;
            if (dots.length === 0) {
                xycircle();
            }
        }
    };

    if (hit)
        score++
    else
        gameover = true;
};

function scorer() {
    fill(20, 75, 200);
    rect(0, 0, 1080, 75);
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    text(score, 950, 50)
    text(timeremaning, 900, 50)
    fill(255, 255, 255);
};

function timer() {
  let time = Date.now();
   timeremaning = 60000
   setInterval(() => {
      timeremaning--
      if (timeremaning <= 0) { gameend(); gameover = true }
   }, 1)
};

function gameend() {
    background(255, 0, 0);
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    text("GAME OVER", 540, 400);
    text("Your score was " + score, 540, 420);
};
timer()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks man, I really should have caught that one. I really appreciate it

Comment: Glad it solved your issue.  Please accept the answer if so.